# Porve that the extension of $f(x)$ which is a continuous function in $E$ (a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$) has a continuous extension in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification

Here's my attempt to the proof:

Since $E$ is a closed set so $E^c=(a_1,b_1) \cup (a_2,b_2) \cup .... \cup (a_k,b_k)...$
(every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as the countable union  of disjoint open intervals).

We define the function $f_i(x)=f(a_i)+\frac{(x-a_i)}{b_i-a_i}(f(b_i)-f(a_i))$ in the interval $(a_i,b_i)$.

We define ,

$g(x)=f(x),  x \in E \\ f_i(x), x \in (a_i,b_i) $

We need to show that $g(x)$ is a continuous function . So , we need to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that $ |g(x)-g(c)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ , whenever $|x-c| < \frac{\delta}{2}$.

I am taking two cases :

**case$1$**:if $c \in E^c$,then $c \in (a_i,b_i)$.The function $g(x)$ takes the value $f_i(x)$ in the interval $(a_i,b_i)$ and so there will exist a $\delta1 >0$ for every $\epsilon >0$ such that
$ |f_i(x)-f_i(c)|<\epsilon$ , whenever $|x-c| < \delta1$ and $x \in (a_i,b_i)$.Since $c$ is an interior point of the set so we can get $(c-\delta_2,c+\delta_2) \subseteq (a_i,b_i)$, let $\delta = min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$, then $(c-\delta,c+\delta) \subseteq (a_i,b_i)$. $ |g(x)-g(c)|<\epsilon$ , whenever $|x-c| < \delta$.

**Case 2**: If $c\in E$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that $ |g(x)-g(c)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ , whenever $|x-c| < \delta$, and $x\in E$.

**subcase $1$**:if $(c- \delta,c+\delta) \cap E^c =\phi$ then $g(x)$ is continuous at $c$.

**subcase $2$**:if$(c,c+\delta)$ consists of countable no of points $a_i<a_{i+1}<a_{i+2}<...$ and $(c-\delta,c)$ can consists of points $b_k>b_{k+1}>b_{k+2}>...$.Any other case would not hold true as that would imply $c \in E^c$, which would be a contradiction.

Now let $lim_{x \to a_i^+}(f_i(x))=f(a_i)$[I have been able to show that $a_i \in E$]  then we know that by the definition of limits there exists a $\delta_1$ such that $|f_i(x)-f(a_i)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ when $x \in (a_i,a_i+\delta_1)$ , also $lim_{x \to b_k^+}(f_k(x))=f(b_k)$ and by the similar definition we know that there exists a $\delta_2$ such that $|f_k(x)-f(b_k)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ when $x \in (b_k-\delta_2,b_k)$ .Let $d= min\{|a_i + \delta_1-c|,|b_k-\delta_2-c|\}$ then $d>0$.Then in the interval $(c-d,c+d)$ we can see that $|f(x)-f(a_i)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}...*1*$ and also $|f_i(x)-f(a_i)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}...*2*$ , now a similar situation arises from $f(b_i)$ thus using the equation *1* and *2* we can conclude that $|g(x) - g(c)|<\epsilon$ in inte interval $(c-d,c+d)$.

*subcase$3$* and *subcase 4* will consists of cases which have elements $a_i,a_{i+1},...$ in the interval $(c,c+\delta)$ and the other will have elements $b_k,b_{k-1},...$ in the intervals $(c-\delta,c)$.

I know there are many answers to the question but I would be very thankful if someone goes through my one.I was trying to solve Rudin on my own and here's my very humble attemt to question no $5$ of chapter $4$(continuity).

Comment: First problem: it is not the case that all closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a disjoint union of closed intervals. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556876/can-closed-sets-in-real-line-be-written-as-a-union-of-disjoint-closed-intervals) question.

Comment: I havent really assumed that . I dont even know whether such a thing would be true

Comment: However every open set can be written as a countable union of disjoint intervals

Comment: I failed at reading, sorry.

Comment: I understand , it must have been a bit confusing but can you just point out where are you having problem then maybe I can rectify  that or try to explain my intuition

Comment: I think that you can sharply simplify the proof in case 2, because if you interpolate between two points that are very close to g(c) then the result must itself be very close to g(c).

Comment: I dont understand @mjez maybe you could explain it a bit more

Comment: I just meant that, with your definition of $f_i$, if $x$ is between $a_i$ and $b_i$ then $f_i(x)$ must be between $f(a_i)$ and $f(b_i)$. But for $x$ close enough to $c$ then $f(a_i)$ and $f(b_i)$ will be at distance at most $\epsilon$ from $f(c) = g(c)$.