# Boundedness of continuous functions on compact sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

Let $E$ and $F$ be two metric spaces. If $K$ is a compact subset of $E$ then a continuous function $f:K\to F$ is always bounded and reachs its maximum.

What happens if we replace $K$ by a closed bounded set $C$ ?

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Sorry, but what's wrong with my question ?

Comment: bumped this question back up to zero because I honestly see no problem with it. If you're gonna call someone out, it's much better to actually tell them explicitly what was wrong.

Comment: @SamuelYusim Thanks, I am new here, so I would be happy if someone tells me what's wrong.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday I learned the theorem that says a continuous function on a compact set is bounded, so I asked myself what happens if we consider a bounded closed set instead of compact ? For example this question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/is-0-1-a-countable-disjoint-union-of-closed-sets has 44 upvotes despite the fact that it doesn't give any motivation. This is exactly how my question is, it is not that kind of questions where I can motivate the problem.

Comment: You know what doesn't help someone get answers suited to their needs? Downvoting their question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb R$ with the metric $d(x,y)=\min\{1,|x-y|\}$. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the function $f(x)=x$. Verify that $\mathbb R$ is closed and bounded and notice that $f$ is not bounded.

Remark: The point is that the "correct" notion of boundedness in metric spaces is that of "total boundedness". For metric spaces a set is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. This example metric is very useful for finding counterexamples like these. You may want to distinguish between the two copies of $\mathbb{R}$ here.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, of course. Corrected!