# In $\mathbb R^p$:Every open subset is the union of a countable collection of closed sets & every open set is the countable union of disjoint open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove/Disprove that :

$(i)$ Every open Set in $\mathbb R^p$ can be written as the union of countable number of disjoint open Sets.

$(ii)$ Every open subset of $\mathbb R^p$ is the union of a countable collection of closed sets.

I was able to look at some similar posts asking this problem; but one seemed to be using the other and vice versa and seem convoluted.

Unfortunately, I have no idea on how to move forward. Can anyone please help me in preparing a proof for both of these problems?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: An open set can be written as the union of itself. Maybe you require these disjoint open sets to satisfy a certain property.

Comment: But, it's not disjoint from itself?

Comment: Maybe: (Pairwise) disjoint *connected* open sets?

Comment: Only *several sets* $(U_i)_J$ can be disjoint, meaning that $U_i\cap U_j=\emptyset$ whenever $i\ne j$.

Comment: Consider for open $O \neq X$ and natural $n$: $F_n(O) = \{ x \in O: d(x, X \setminus O) \ge \frac{1}{n} \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show:

1. Every open set is union of balls with rational radius and rational center.
2. Every open ball is a countable union of closed balls.

This gives *(ii)*. For *(i)*, given two points in your open set, say that they are equivalent iff there is a continuous path between them, completely contained in the open set. Argue that this is indeed an equivalence relation, and that its components (equivalence classes) are open. Now use that $\mathbb Q^n$ is dense in $\mathbb R^n$, so there can be no more than countably many equivalence classes.

Comment: Thank you but I am afraid that the text I am reading has not even introduced dense sets ..

Comment: Surely you can show that every open set contains an element of $\mathbb Q^n$.

Comment: Uhm, so, to prove that every open set in $\mathbb R^p$ contains an element of $\mathbb Q^n$, we need to prove that every open set in $\mathbb R$ contains an element of $\mathbb Q$ ? This should be true since, any open interval contains infinite rational numbers. Am I correct?

Comment: Sure, that's one way. And the stronger property you indicate is indeed true.

Comment: Okay .. So, I now say that any two points $x,y$ in the open set are equivalent iff they are connected? And then prove this is an equivalence relation.  This seems true since : $~~(a)~ x \sim x ~~(b)~x\sim y  \implies y \sim x~~$   $ (c) x \sim y ~, ~y \sim z$ $\implies x \sim z $ . Hence, this is an equivalence relation

Comment: having proved that the above represents an equivalence relation, we need to prove that the equivalence classes are open. Can you give me some hints on how to prove it?

Comment: If you have a path from $ x $ to $ y $ in your open set, and $ z $ is in a ball centered at $ y $ and contained in the set, then there is a path from $ x $ to $ z $ in the set: First go to $ y $, and then go from $ y $ to $ z $ in a straight line. This shows the component that contains $ x $ is open.

Comment: in the second question , what if we assume these closed sets are pair disjoint?

Comment: @hctb That's a good question. In that case you can't. This was first shown by Sierpiński.

Comment: @hctb See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/6314/462) for the (key) argument.