# Prove that there does not exist a sequence $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ such that $\bigcup_{n}I_n=[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Prove that there does not exist a sequence $I_n=[a_n,b_n], n=1,2,\ldots $ of nonempty, pairwise disjoint intervals such that $\cup_{n}I_n=[0,1]$.

**My solution -- is it correct?**

My idea is that taking an open cover $\{A_{\alpha_i}\}$ of  $[0,1]$ then $(\cup_{i}A_{\alpha_i})\cap (\cup_i I_i)=\cup_{i}(A_{\alpha_i}\cap I_i)$ is a open cover of $[0,1]$ as well (correspondence to induced topology).

Moreover, $(A_{\alpha_i}\cap I_i)\cap (A_{\alpha_j}\cap I_j)=\emptyset$ with $i\ne j$.

Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there exists $N$ such that $ \cup_{i=1}^N(A_{\alpha_i}\cap I_i) \supset[0,1]$.

However, $[0,1] \supsetneq \cup_{i=1}^N(A_{\alpha_i}\cap I_i)$ since $\cup_{i=1}^N(A_{\alpha_i}\cap I_i)$ and $I_n=[a_n,b_n], n=1,2,\ldots $ of nonempty, pairwise disjoint intervals.

So, we get contradition $[0,1] \subsetneq [0,1]$.

Could you please give your idea about my solution? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The sentence beginning with "Moreover" seems to be incomplete: something about that intersection...

Comment: You wrote : "$(\cup_{i}A_{\alpha_i})\cap (\cup_i I_i)=\cup_{i}(A_{\alpha_i}\cap I_i)$" You need $i,j$ on the right,

Comment: This looks like a Baire category theorem problem to me.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/is-0-1-a-countable-disjoint-union-of-closed-sets/216595#216595

Comment: @DonAntonio: I just edited.Thank Taylor very much. I know there exists other way to solve. Could you please give your idea about my method?

Comment: You can only have a countable union: There are at most countably many (closed/open) balls of positive radius in $R^n$.

Comment: @user52523 u said pairwise disjoint then this is trivial.

Comment: Just take an arbitrary such sequence and describe its union. Note it is not as desired.

Comment: Note these closed sets are all internal. Thus it is equivalent to a countable closed partition on the reals.

Comment: @Behnam moreover their centers cannot be dense.

Comment: I now have a completely correct solution!

Comment: @Behnam "There are at most countably many (closed/open) balls of positive radius in Rn" Already with a given center, there are uncountably many.

Comment: I have meant "pairwise disjoint" collection.

Comment: @Behnam So, you are just stating the desired conclusion? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: But the proof of my claim is so simple and straightforward. Take increasing sequence of balls of radius $1,2,3,...$ all centered at origin. One of them must contain infinitly many of our collection. Now, If there are uncountably many disjoint positive radius balls within a huge bounded ball, then their union will have a measure equal to infinity ("sum" of uncountably many positive numbers is never bounded.) However, the union is contained in a ball with finite measure. Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I think the equation $(\cup_{i}A_{\alpha_i})\cap (\cup_i I_i)=\cup_{i}(A_{\alpha_i}\cap I_i)$ does not make sense. $A_\alpha's$ has any union and $I_n's$ has countable union. So how do you define the union in the right side? There is a very easy way of solving this if you like to try. To the contrary assume such sequence exists. Then the set (Say $E$) that contains $a_n's$ and $b_n's$ is countable. Now show that $E$ is a perfect set. A perfect set in $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. Thus we get a contradiction.

Comment: The indexing set of the $A_\alpha$ can be chosen so that it is finite, given that the closed unit interval is compact.

Comment: Ok. But then how do we have intersection for the same index on the RHS? I mean it should be corrected as $A_{\alpha_i}\cap I_j$