# Continuous and uncountable function

Tags: continuity

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$  be a non-constant continuous function. Show that $f ([a,b])$ is uncountable.

Comment: Do you know the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Obviously. Why not ?

Comment: But how can i say f is uncountable?

Comment: "$f$ is uncountable" makes no sense. You want to show that the set of values of  $f$ is uncountable.

Comment: Yes yes . I want to mean f([a,b]) .

Comment: But how can I do this ?

Comment: The proof is one or two sentences using the intermediate value theorem. If that's not enough of a hint you'll have to wait until someone decides to provide the answer for you.

Comment: Since f is non-constant without lose of any generality let a <b be two points so that f (a) <f (b) . Then IVT \thereexists c\in mathbb {R} s.t. f (a)<c <f (b). Hence there are uncountably many such c and f maps every such c. Thau f ([a,b]) is uncountable. Is it right ,Sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One elegant approach is to use topological fact, that [continuous image of connected set is connected](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Connected_Space_is_Connected). Connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are precisely intervals and singletons. Since $f$ is not constant, $f([a,b])$ is nondegenerated interval, and thus  uncountable.

More elementary approach is to use [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) as mentioned by others. By assumption there exists $x_1,x_2\in [a, b]$ such that $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$. By intermediate value theorem if $y\in (f(x_1),f(x_2))$ then there exist $x\in(x_1,x_2)\cup(x_2,x_1)$ such that $f(x)=y$. Note, that $y$ was arbitrary, and $(x_1,x_2)\cup(x_2,x_1)\subset[a,b]$, so $[f(x_1),f(x_2)]\subset f([a,b])$. Therefore $f([a,b])$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use Darboux Property. If a continuous function attains two values $y_1,y_2$, then ... ?

Comment: Darboux? It is about derivatives.

Comment: Explain it pls. How will it be applicable

Comment: @egreg Are you sure? Maybe. I had in mind Intermediate Value Theorem. In Poland it is sometimes called Darboux Property. So, both continuous functions and derivatives do admit Darbous property. Please look at this: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Darboux_property

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. I seem to have the following argument. Suppose it is not uncountable. Let us denote
$$
f([0,1]) \triangleq \{x_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}.
$$
Now, using the continuity of $f(\cdot)$, note that each of $A_n\triangleq f^{-1}(\{x_n\})$ is closed. But then,
$$
[0,1] = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(\{x_n\}) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n
$$
would hold. After this point, note that $A_n$'s are all disjoint. So it boils down arguing whether $[0,1]$ can be written as a countable union of disjoint closed sets.

Apparently, the answer is no, and given in this link : [Is [0,1] a countable disjoint union of closed sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/is-0-1-a-countable-disjoint-union-of-closed-sets).