# Is it possible that there is a connected topological space without path-connected subspace?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Is it possible that there is a connected topological space without path-connected subspace?

Furtherly ~ 
Is that any connected topological space $X$ always has dense path-connected subspace?

Or

Is that any non-trivial connected topological space $X$ has the property:
$\forall x\in X$ there exists a path $p:[0, 1]\to X$ such that $x$ is an accumulation point of the image of $p$ in X.

I'm wondering that one of statement above is a sufficient and necessary condition of a connected space. But I can't find any suitable keyword to google this. Can anyone advance?

If there's a counterexample, then it would be really interesting.

Comment: the pseudo-arc is connected, but each path component is a singleton. It is a planar continuum, so a metric space too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc also http://topo.math.auburn.edu/pm/pseudodraw.pdf also https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Pseudo-arc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $X = \Bbb N$ in the cofinite topology, then $X$ is connected but any continuous $p: [0,1] \to X$ is constant. As noted in the comments, Hausdorff examples also exist, but we cannot get regular Hausdorff countable connected spaces (as then maps onto $[0,1]$ exist by normality).

Comment: The last fact is a consequence of Sierpinski's classic theorem that a continuum cannot be a non-trivial at most countable union of pairwise disjoint closed subsets.

Comment: See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6314/4280) for more info.

Comment: Wow~ nice example. What about add the Hausdorff condition, is it still possible to find an counterexample?

Comment: Thank for your reference information~

Comment: @yoyo, yes make it a countable connected *Hausdorff* space. They also exist, see [$\pi$-base](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=connected%20%2B%20Countable%20%2B%20%24T_2%24)