# Real Analysis Books

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, baire-category

I was trying to solve the problem: [Is $[0,1]$ a countable disjoint union of closed sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6314/809050) I find a theorem which is very interesting:

> **Theorem (Sierpiński).** If a continuum $X$ has a countable cover $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ by pairwise disjoint closed subsets, then at most one of the sets $X_i$ is non-empty.

Can anyone please suggest me some books on Real Analysis or Point Set Topology, which contains theorem of this type?

Answer (score 1):

Two books that have this result are [**Topology. II**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004RZKZP4) by Kuratowski (1968) (I don't know the precise location, but the very end of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/48970/15780) says where it's located in the 1950 French edition, which should help you find where it's located in the 1968 English edition) and [**Set Theory**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821838350) by Hausdorff (English translation of 1935 3rd edition, end of §29.4, pp. 185-186).

Two books that contain many classical point set theory results, but not the Sierpiński result itself (as far as I can tell), are [**Set Theory. With an Introduction to Real Point Sets**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461488532) by Dasgupta (2014) and [**Point Set Theory**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K0V9TIC) by Morgan (1990).