# Countable $T_1$ spaces are totally path disconnected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Steen & Seebach, Counterexamples in Topology, have the following as problem 30 on [p. 206](https://books.google.com/books?id=Uz0rV250nhsC&pg=PA206&lpg=PA206&dq=%22totally+path+disconnected%22+%22countable%22&source=bl&ots=TINlr9YOAw&sig=ACfU3U1qBx9m9EvFO7OHsrvVkbvKBxNjUw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxkujF5bj4AhX3j4kEHdXJDEw4HhDoAXoECBEQA#v=onepage):

> Every countable $T_1$ space is totally path disconnected.

I can see why a Hausdorff countable space $X$ is [totally path disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space), i.e., all paths into $X$ are constant.  Suppose there is a non-constant path $f:[0,1]\to X$ from $x$ to $y$ with $x\ne y$.  The image of the path is then path-connected and Hausdorff.  And such a space is arc-connected (Willard, Corollary 31.6, consequence of the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem).  Since $x$ and $y$ are distinct points, any arc joining them has the cardinality of the continuum, and so the space $X$ cannot be countable.

What is the correct argument if we just assume $T_1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you had a continuous non-constant $f:[0,1]\to X$.

Since $X$ is $T_1$, the one-element set containing $p$ is a closed set for all $p\in X$.

Therefore $[0,1]$ would be the union of countably many (and more than one, because the function is not constant) disjoint nonempty closed sets $f^{-1}(p)$.

But this is impossible: [Is $[0,1]$ a countable disjoint union of closed sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/is-0-1-a-countable-disjoint-union-of-closed-sets?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Nice.  And the image of $f$ (non-constant) cannot be finite either, as that would provide a nontrivial finite partition of $[0,1]$ by closed sets, which is not possible because $[0,1]$ is connected.

Comment: @PatrickR . Countable means "finite or countably infinite" so that uncountable means the same as not countable.